# Forgot password feature using QT and SQLITE DB

Tags: database, sqlite, qt, authentication, change-password

I'm trying to build my login screen in QT using SQLITE database. I've already successfully implemented sign up and log in features and I'd like to add "Forgot password" feature as well. The user should input his email & phone number he used while signing up and if it was found in db then the user can set a new password. The problem is that I don't understand what function I should use to replace a user's password with exactly that email&phone number. How to select the right row in the db through the code. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that you required the password recovery process and not about "how to query a record". If you need data level help, we need the table structure as well)

This is how I did for one of my client some time ago. If you need more clarification, please comment.

1. Use 2-factor authentication.
2. Verify the email or phone # via an API,
3. If Existing, then send an OTP to that phone # or to the email address selected by the user.
   (I used a DB function to generate the OTP for my requirement and below I attached that code for your reference)
4. Better assign a TTL (Time to leave) value to that OTP to remove it after some time.

I'll provide you with a sample process that I used some time ago for the same kind of purpose.

[image: Sample Screens]

Sample Table and a DB function (Postgres DB)

```
CREATE TABLE myf_t_otp (
    otp_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    otp_category int8 NOT NULL,
    otp_otp varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    otp_user_name varchar(100) NULL,
    otp_user_id int8 NULL,
    otp_value varchar(100) NULL, 
    otp_code varchar(60) NULL,
    otp_code2 varchar(60) NULL,
    otp_description varchar(500) NULL,
    otp_active int8 NULL,
    otp_status int8 NULL,
    otp_country int8 NULL,
    otp_company int8 NULL,
    otp_department int8 NULL,
    created_by varchar(30) NULL,
    created_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    last_modified_by varchar(30) NULL,
    last_modified_date timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT myf_t_otp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (otp_id)
);
```

_otp_category  = 'Mobile' or 'Web App'
_otp_value  = 'email or Phone #'
_otp_user_name = 'User name'
other parameters are optional

> Throgh this "intRandNum := cast(random() * 100000 as int);" system
> will create a random # and return it to the user. Send email and SMS
> manage through a JAVA application

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myf_fun_otp(_otp_category bigint, _otp_value character varying, _otp_user_name character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying, _otp_user_id bigint DEFAULT '-1'::integer, _created_by character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying, _otp_description character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying, _otp_active bigint DEFAULT 1, _otp_status bigint DEFAULT 1, _otp_country bigint DEFAULT '-1'::integer, _otp_company bigint DEFAULT '-1'::integer)
 RETURNS bigint
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    intRandNum int4;
    strValue varchar(10);

begin
    
    -- Generate Random values for OTP
    intRandNum := cast(random() * 100000 as int);
    strValue = rpad(cast(intRandNum as varchar(100)), 5,'0');
    intRandNum := cast(strValue  as int);


    -- Reset the previoud OTP's if any and disable before new one
    update myf_t_otp set
        otp_active = 0
    where otp_value = _otp_value and otp_category = _otp_category;
    
    -- Insert the new OTP
    INSERT INTO myf_t_otp
    (otp_category, otp_otp, otp_user_name, otp_user_id, otp_value, otp_description, 
    otp_active, otp_status, otp_country, otp_company,
    created_by)
    VALUES(_otp_category, cast(intRandNum as varchar(60)), _otp_user_name, _otp_user_id, _otp_value, _otp_description, _otp_active, _otp_status,
    _otp_country, _otp_company, _created_by);

    return intRandNum;

 
END
$function$
;
```